# Has there ever been any examples of persecuted people hiding treasure in British churches before they flee somewhere?

Tags: britain, church

(I'm writing an historical fiction story.) Have there been cases of persecuted people who hid their wealth in a church? Who would they be? Who are they fleeing persecution from? Why were they being persecuted? Where did they try to escape to?

Comment: When you say 'hiding', do you mean that the church is unware of the treasure too or simply that the treasure is left in the safekeeping of the church but hidden from public knowledge?

Comment: Good question. I think the church is unaware of the treasure.